# Geocoding postgreSQL table from addresses to get latitude and longitude

Tags: postgresql, google-maps, geocoding, talend, google-geocoding-api

I have a table in postgresql database with my clients infos. The table contains more than 430 000 records and i should generate the latitude and longitude from the address column for any record in the table.

Please can you suggest me any solution to that. I had a look on Google maps geocoding API in Talend open studio ( using tGoogleGeocoder) but it is very limited.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please also elaborate a bit on the types of records you have? I mean, are they streets, cities, monuments, etc.?

Comment: Anyway, you might wanna take a look at GeoNames: http://www.geonames.org/

Comment: @JimJones thanks for this comment, addresses can be streets and postal code of specified country

Comment: @JimJones how can i use it with database to update my recods ?

Comment: Well, I'm not aware of any postgresql extension that does this job. I would suggest you to write a script (using shell, java, c#, etc..) to download and parse the coordinates, based on this table of yours, and then store them in a new geometry column. GeoData enrichment can be quite annoying, specially when it comes to disambiguate place names... but it is perfectly feasible.